# Is it possible to get which tab is loading ajax page without GET?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-tabs

very easy example:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="tab_index.php" id="ctx-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="tab_index.php" id="ctx-5">Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tabs-spacer" style="height:0px"></div>
</div>
```

And now the problem: I'd like to know which tab "calls" tab_index.php.

The easiest solution would be: tab_index.php?ctx=1, but i don't want to use GET for security reasons.

Is is possible at all?

the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sledgehammer/M8jYA/

Comment: could you explain these security concerns a bit more? It's `GET` with or without the query string...

Comment: Yes, of course its GET, but i don't want to pass the parameter ctx in url

Comment: So from whom are you trying to hide this parameter and why is my question. Safe to assume when you say you want to know which tab "calls" it, you mean you want your `tab_index.php` to have this info? As in the answer below, its easy to just add a click handler to record this tab-click...

Comment: exactly - I want my tab_index.php to have this info.

Comment: Ok, so this really sounds like a question about where to store state in a single page app? You could probably use an HTTP session, cookies, local storage, store state in a DB, or (mis)use a HTTP verb like `POST` to do what you want, but before making any reccommendations, I'd like to know more about the why of what you're doing.

Comment: because nobody (almost) can see what is in tab_index.php (code) so it's harder to find what has to be changed to broke the code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38697/discussion-between-zach-l-and-sledgehammerpl)

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the click on your tab link `$('a[href="tab_index.php"]')`

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href="tab_index.php"]').click(function(){
       var clickedTab = $(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

jsFiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/Zdw37/6/

Comment: nice (i would use it in other place) but I need something like this in tab_index.php, not in the main script.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use GET, you could use POST:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
      <li>
          <form action="tab_index.php" method="POST">
              <input type="submit" value="Tab1" name="tab" />
          </form>
      </li>
      <li>
          <form action="tab_index.php" method="POST">
              <input type="submit" value="Tab2" name="tab" />
          </form>
      </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tabs-spacer" style="height:0px"></div>
</div>
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/KTmga/ (check your browser's network console)

Comment: But it wouldn't work in jquery tabs.... look here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sledgehammer/M8jYA/